# sum is not working after taking union multiple column in knexjs mysql

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, node.js, knex.js

I need a sum of 4 column ,I am doing that by first taking union then running sum

```
  db.select("gen-acute-sales-before-returns").table('sales')
  .union(function() {
    this.select("gen-acute-sales-after-returns").table('sales')
  })
  .union(function(){
    this.select("gen-chronic-sales-before-returns").table('sales')
  })
  .union(function(){
    this.select("gen-chronic-sales-after-returns").table('sales')
  })
  .sum({totalSales:"gen-acute-sales-before-returns"})
  .then(result => res.json(result))
```

Problem is that I am getting a union table but **sum** is not working

Comment: Please define "sum is not working".  Current results and desired results would be a good start here.

Comment: Why are you using `UNION` in the first place? Select `gen-acute-sales-after-returns + gen-chronic-sales-before-returns + gen-chronic-sales-after-returns` and return the sum of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just add general knex debugging guidance here, since the question is pretty ambiguous.

Check out what query is generated by calling `.toSQL()` for the query builder. Then you can see if the generated query has something wrong.

```
console.log(
  db.select("gen-acute-sales-before-returns").table('sales')
  .union(function() {
    this.select("gen-acute-sales-after-returns").table('sales')
  })
  .union(function(){
    this.select("gen-chronic-sales-before-returns").table('sales')
  })
  .union(function(){
    this.select("gen-chronic-sales-after-returns").table('sales')
  })
  .sum({totalSales:"gen-acute-sales-before-returns"}).toSQL().sql
);
```

It is completely possible that there is bug in knex's union method (wouldn't be the first time).